# hierarchical clustering - finding the observations in each group

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have massive amounts of data with more than 10 covariates. Currently, I am using hierarchical clustering. On the dendrogram, I cannot see the labels clearly because there are so many.

-- Is there a way to find out which observations are in which group?

(I am using R)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with `cutree`:

```
## some data
set.seed(1234)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=10)

## clustering
hc <- hclust(dist(x))
plot(hc)

## k = number of groups
cutree(hc, k=5)

## or:
## h: height in cluster dendrogram
cutree(hc, h=6)
```